# Install Ubuntu Desktop from Ubuntu Mini?

Tags: system-installation

I've installed Ubuntu 12.10 from PXE, using the linux & initrd.gz files and I'd like to update it to Ubuntu Desktop (with unity, the shopping len and everything in between).

I've heard that I can do it by installing the 'ubuntu-deskop' meta package, however I wonder if anyone has actually done it and if that's enough to get an identical Ubuntu installation as if I had installed it with the LiveDvd.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the complete Ubuntu desktop then you have to do as

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

If you would like to get only the Unity then 
`sudo apt-get install unity` is enough .

So if you have install with ubuntu desktop command as given , then [all these](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/ubuntu-desktop) packages will installs in your PC .